# ArgoCD deletes grafana service expose

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm new, and exploring ArgoCD, Helm, Grafana, and Prometheus. I found a cool repo (https://github.com/naturalett/continuous-delivery) on how to deploy all the services using Argo, it's working great, but I'm unable to reach Grafana.

I'm running a k3s on a proxmox server. My proxmox server IP is 192.168.10.250, my k3s server is 192.168.10.137 and my grafana service is on

```
service/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana              ClusterIP      10.43.175.176
```

If I expose the service:

```
kubectl expose service/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana --type=NodePort --target-port=3000 --name=grafana-ext -n argocd
```

ArgoCD will delete the NodePort. I assume it is because it's not on the manifest.

The port forward is not working also. I'm not able to reach the Grafana UI:

```
kubectl port-forward service/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana -n argocd 9092:80
```

So my question is, how can I add the Service NodePort to the manifest? It's using helm charts, but how can I achieve it?

Comment: Your question is not focused enough on one issue. Here are a few ways to do it: check if the Helm Chart exposes an option to do it, use Kustomize to patch the result of the Helm chart (compatible with ArgoCD as well), don't use NodePort (instead add an Ingress for example). That being said if the port forward do not work, there's another issue to fix first, you might want to focus on that first.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author in order to move it to the answer space).*

I was able to solve it by creating a yaml with the NodePort configuration and passing the yaml to the kustomization!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grafana-nodeport
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    release: kube-prometheus-stack
selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30009
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
```